# Bloomberg Add-In Total Return Monthly Ticker/ function

Tags: add-in, bloomberg

So I want to extract the monthly total returns of a rather large selection of stocks (hsci) over a period of 10y+.

I haven't found an option to do that directly with the bloomberg panel (just at 1 point of time not the whole time series (120+ data points per stock).

With internet research/ asking people a possible solution came up:

Use the Excel Addin with historical end of day data and find the total return function and set monthly data. then just replace the ticker of the stock in the formula and that's suppose to be it.

I cannot set it up though. Can I anyone walk me through? I cannot find the correct total return function first of all and don't know how to put the pieces together.

Hope this question isn't too easy. I feel already sort of embarassed.

Kind regards

SLC

Comment: have you asked the help desk?

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, you need to have a Bloomberg Professional subscription, it's not clear from your question if you have one. If you do, install  Bloomberg Professional (Bloomberg Terminal) PC. You can download it from [here](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/downloads/). Installing the Terminal also installs the Excel add-on. After installing, log into the Terminal, then open Excel, click the Bloomberg menu in the ribbon, click Import Data, Real-Time/Historical, choose the stocks and date range and follow the wizard.

If you don't have a Bloomberg Professional subscription, you can contact a Bloomberg sales rep, but they don't come cheap.